# I can't understand how this function works

Tags: c++, function

I have this program and i'm having a very hard time understanding exactly how this function works and why does it do what it does. I think it has something to do with operation precedence, but i'm not really sure. Can anyone explain to me in steps how does this compile?

The program is this:

```
void s1( char dest[], char src[] )
{ int i = 0;

  while( dest[i++] = src[i++] );
}

int main()

{
char a[100]="abcdef";
char b[100]="123456";

s1(a,b);

puts(a);
puts(b);
return 0;

}
```

The output is:
1b3d5f
123456

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This function works by chance. Doing `i++` twice in a single statement is unreliable. Where did you find this piece of cruft?

Comment: it was in my assignment from the uni to figure out what does this functions output.

Comment: @larsmans to me, this is not a matter of chance, at each loop, it replace the destination with the source, but incrementing 2 by 2

Comment: @Samoth The order of operations of the assignment `dest[i++] = src[i++]` is not specified by the standard.

Comment: The correct answer is that it is impossible to determine the output because the code has undefined behaviour. See @larsman 's link. If your professor does not accept your answer, show him [this compiler warning from GCC](http://ideone.com/O0yufP).

Answer (score -1):

As larsmans said, you should not use double incrementation in a condition but the output is normal :

## i = 0

```
{
dest[0] = src[0]; // src[0] is 1
i = i + 2; // i++ and i ++
}
```

## i = 2

```
{
dest[2] = src[2]; // src[2] is 3
i = i + 2; // i++ and i ++
}
```

And so on...

Which explain your output is 1b3d5f...

Comment: This answer is wrong - the line `while( dest[i++] = src[i++] );` has undefined behaviour. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points). Also, [click here](http://ideone.com/O0yufP) to see the warning that GCC emits with the OP's code.

Answer (score -2):

After the call to the function `s1(a, b)` is made...

```
dest = "abcdef"
src = "123456"
```

`i++` is the post-increment of i...ie: current value of i is used, and then incremented
hence in the first run of while loop, `i = 0` is used...
therefore, `dest[0] = src[0] = 1`...
now i is incremented twice, since there is two i++ in the loop...
now i = 2
therefore `dest[2] = src[2] = 3`
so on ...
finally `dest = 1b3d5f` and `src` remains unchanged

Comment: This answer is wrong - the line `while( dest[i++] = src[i++] );` has undefined behaviour. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points). Also, [click here](http://ideone.com/O0yufP) to see the warning that GCC emits with the OP's code.